# Science fantasy series from the '80s involving magical areas and a forest with plants that are like items

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I read a science fantasy series back in the '80s involving a kingdom with magical areas, a forest with magical plants that were like items of the same name. (Ex: lady slippers, ex: violets are violence.) A monster under the bed was a friend to the young girl.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking over the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details you can think to add. The more info you can provide, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you.

Comment: This sounds like [*Xanth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth).

Answer (score 17):

A 1980s book series about a magical land built from cliches and bad puns pretty much has to be Piers Anthony's [*Xanth*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?581).

Doing some quick searches, the lady slipper plant and unpleasant violets show up in [*The Source of Magic*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5305) (1979) and a monster under the bed features in [*Dragon on a Pedestal*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2067) (1983).

Quotes from Google books:

> Bink changed the subject. "We have a delicate young **lady-slipper plant** just blooming; I think it will bear its first pair of slippers soon."
>
> <sub>*The Source of Magic*, [ref](https://books.google.ca/books?id=MHL6EGqgHZkC&pg=PA21&q=lady+slipper&hl=en)</sub>

> Meanwhile the Magician was trying to avoid the **snapping jaws of dog-tooth violets** and dandelions, while a hawkweed made little swoops at his head.  Bink would have laughed—but had too many problems of his own.
>
> <sub>*ibid*, [ref](https://books.google.ca/books?id=MHL6EGqgHZkC&q=violets)</sub>

> Irene suppressed an illicit smirk.  She had always been afraid of the **monster under the bed** and, in childhood, had tended to leap into bed, not from any joy of sleeping, but to avoid the ankle-grabbing mitt.
>
> <sub>*Dragon on a Pedestal*, [ref](https://books.google.ca/books?id=nEhxkNzXYzIC&pg=PA8&q=%22monster%20under%20the%20bed%22&hl=en)</sub>

Comment: I remember the other one OP references, with the violet growing in the middle of the road, which was frowned upon because people didn't want more violets in the median. But I don't remember which book it was in. I will say that I stopped reading them before Anthony's obsession with young girls' underwear became too obvious.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Unlike my normal practice I can't provide direct quotes from any of these since I ditched them all when I was 18 and realized how problematic they were.

Answer (score 0):

This is Piers Anthony's Xanth series. There are a ton of books in the series. Lightweight reading with lots of puns and wordplay.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  The existing answer already gives this ID; can you provide extra details to make this a better answer?  You might want to read [answer] and take the [tour].